# sequential letter fading not working in sequence, all fade in at same time jQuery

Tags: jquery, sequence, fade

I'm trying to fade in a string of letters, I'm not sure why they aren't fading in at different times.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
$( "#A" ).fadeIn( "500" );
$( "#B" ).fadeIn( "600" );
$( "#C" ).fadeIn( "700" );
$( "#D" ).fadeIn( "800" );
$( "#E" ).fadeIn( "900" );
$( "#F" ).fadeIn( "1000" );
$( "#G" ).fadeIn( "1100" );
$( "#H" ).fadeIn( "1200" );
$( "#I" ).fadeIn( "1300" );
$( "#J" ).fadeIn( "1400" );
$( "#K" ).fadeIn( "1500" );
$( "#L" ).fadeIn( "3600" );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add time as 500, 600, the speed of fading will change but it will start fading at same time. Your code should be

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

     $("#A").fadeIn( 500,function ()
     {
        $("#B").fadeIn( 500,function ()
         {
                $("#C").fadeIn(500,function ()
                 {

                 });
         });
     });
});
```

added callback function which will fade one after the other

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I don't know why code doesn't work the way you would intrinsically think that it would work eg. if you specified longer times then the duration should increase not default... whatever. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: There is a problem in your solution. Even though the process becomes sequential your fadeIn duration will always be 400ms because you have specified 500ms as a string. Use integer values to specify time in milliseconds. Check my answer @janicehoplin

Answer (score 1):

Durations are given in milliseconds(integer value); The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is used. Instead of string if you use integer values you can make this code work.

```
$( "#A" ).fadeIn( 500 );
$( "#B" ).fadeIn( 600 );
```

In your script fadeIn is taking the default time setting in every case.

If you want to work this sequentially

```
$( "#A" ).fadeIn( 500, function() {
$( "#B" ).fadeIn( 100 );
});
```